# Why won't writeRaster save a 4390x4390 raster?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to save a raster in R, which was cropped from [GLC2000](http://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/glc2000/products/glc2000_v1_1_Grid.zip). The resulting raster has 4390 rows and 4390 cols, covering Brazil and part of South America. The command to save it (as a GeoTIFF) is either

```
writeRaster(r1,'Raster1.tif')
```

or

```
writeRaster(r1,'Raster1.tif','GTiff')
```

Both keep trying to save the file for several hours, but they don't even create the file, much less finish the write process.

I doubt that's because of the size of the file (I think the file should at least start saving, with a temporary file appearing, visible or hidden -- none exists). Two other similar TIFF files (almost the same area, though all South America except Brazil is black) have 2.7 MB (indexed, gives errors when opening on Gimp: "Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered", and other tags) and 19.3 MB (also indexed, gives no errors on Gimp).

I don't think it's because of directory permissions, because R could save the script in the same directory (the permissions are drwxr-xr-x, and I'm the owner and the group owner).

There are 11.6 GB available in the specified file system.

I'm using Debian Jessie 64-bit with Gnome 3.14.1, and R 3.3.3 with RStudio 1.0.136.

My processor is a Intel® Core™ i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz × 4, with 7.8 GiB RAM.

Should writeRaster take so long to save a raster which is not even that big? What may be going wrong?

EDIT

So I'm trying with smaller sizes.

```
ext <- extent(-67,-65,-1,1)
r1 <- crop(r,ext)
dim(r1) # 224 224   1
writeRaster(r1,'Raster1','GTiff') # works

ext <- extent(-68,-64,-2,2)
r1 <- crop(r,ext)
dim(r1) # 448 448   1
writeRaster(r1,'Raster2','GTiff') # works

ext <- extent(-69,-63,-3,3)
r1 <- crop(r,ext)
#Warning message:
#In .getRat(x, ratvalues, ratnames, rattypes) : NAs introduced by coercion
dim(r1) # 672 672   1
writeRaster(r1,'Raster3','GTiff') # takes forever
```

Looks like the error is the NAs being introduced by coercion, this prevents the file from being saved. I've tried

```
r1[is.na(r1)] <- 0
```

But still the file won't be saved. Why in the world would crop introduce NAs to a common raster, if I'm cropping inside the limits of the raster?

```
extent(r)
# class       : Extent
# xmin        : -180.0045
# xmax        : 179.9955
# ymin        : -56.01339
# ymax        : 89.99554
```

EDIT 2

```
> levels(r)
[[1]]
   ID     COUNT                                               CLASSNAMES
1   1  12875179                       Tree Cover, broadleaved, evergreen
2   2   8688097               Tree Cover, broadleaved, deciduous, closed
3   3   4099003                 Tree Cover, broadleaved, deciduous, open
4   4  15080165                     Tree Cover, needle-leaved, evergreen
5   5   8054159                     Tree Cover, needle-leaved, deciduous
6   6   5606446                              Tree Cover, mixed leaf type
7   7    579763               Tree Cover, regularly flooded, fresh water
8   8    115705              Tree Cover, regularly flooded, saline water
9   9   4269938            Mosaic: Tree Cover / Other natural vegetation
10 10    587270                                        Tree Cover, burnt
11 11   3195387                      Shrub Cover, closed-open, evergreen
12 12  15605651                      Shrub Cover, closed-open, deciduous
13 13  17560702                            Herbaceous Cover, closed-open
14 14  23573022                  Sparse herbaceous or sparse shrub cover
15 15   3089962          Regularly flooded shrub and/or herbaceous cover
16 16  21692769                             Cultivated and managed areas
17 17   4025653 Mosaic: Cropland / Tree Cover / Other natural vegetation
18 18   3921904              Mosaic: Cropland / Shrub and/or grass cover
19 19  24629888                                               Bare Areas
20 20 471034157                                             Water Bodies
21 21  10660085                                             Snow and Ice
22 22    378999                 Artificial surfaces and associated areas
23 23     29056                                                  No Data
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46832976/1086511).

Comment: does the raster have an attribute table (i.e., what do you get from `levels(r)` ?

Comment: @LoBu Please see EDIT 2.

Comment: the  error message seems to indicate something wrong happening with the RAT. I'd try replacing the labels with something simple and retry. for example:  `levels(r)[[1]]$CLASSNAMES <- letters[1:23]`

Comment: @LoBu Looks like it did the trick. But why?!

Comment: Wild guess is a problem with special characters or length of the labels. As soon as an "offending label" is brought in by the subsetting, you start having problems. You could try to simplify the class names until you understand what is causing the problems.

Comment: Looks like a bug that should be reported to the raster development team... You may add it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree. If you pinpoint what in the labels is causing the problem, it could also be worthy to document it here by replying to your own question, though.

Comment: Ok. Iadded it as an snswer. If you understand what the issue in the classnames is, I suggest you to edit the answer (or tell me and I will do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As by discussion in comments, the error message indicated something wrong happening with the Raster Attribute Table. The problem could be related with special characters or length of the labels. As soon as an "offending label" is brought in by the subsetting, you start having problems.

Simplifying the classnames using

```
levels(r)[[1]]$CLASSNAMES <- letters[1:23]
```

solved the issue.

Looking at this related question [Why is crop introducing NAs to my raster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46832976/1086511) showed that the problem was in having semicolumns (`:`) in the names of the classes, which somehow led to "splitting" the class names while cropping.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46832976/1086511). Do you know how do I update the RAT after the crop, so I can pinpoint the origin of the error?

Comment: looking at the other question, I think that the problem is with the `:` in the names ("Mosaic : ....") which is somehow "splitted", so that you end up with two entries called "Mosaic". Remove the semicolumns from the labels and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I sent an email for the package maintainer, let's see what he will say. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Good. A suggestion: It may be good to "join" the discusions in your two questions, so that there is only one topic and one answer. I'd suggest to keep the other question (which topic is more "focused" - you could change the name to something like " Why is crop introducing NAs on a categorical raster" ?, or "Why is crop failing erratically on a categorical raster ), move the answer there and then delete this thread. Let me know if you agree, and I will move the answer on thatthread.

Comment: Sure, let's move it. I agree.

Comment: Ok. I moved it.

Comment: I don't know if I should delete this post. Someone could always find this question instead of the other. I think I'll just add a link to the other one.

Comment: That's your call. for me both are fine.